# Firefox: Close tab on last "back" action if link was opened from another tab (Safari behavior)

Tags: firefox, safari, tabs

There is a Safari behavior (both mobile and desktop) that I love, but I haven't been able to find a way to replicate in Firefox (desktop) either through preferences or add-ons, and was wondering if anyone else had been able to accomplish it?

Specifically, in Safari, if a tab is opened by clicking a link from another tab (generally, if the link was of format `<a href="..." target="_blank">`), then it can be auto-closed if you trigger a Back navigation action on the newly opened tab without performing any other navigation within it. This is really handy when for example you're reading a page with a list of links, and you click a link to read an article, read it, and then click/keyboard shortcut a Back action and the new tab closes. This pops you back to the original tab with the list of article links, very convenient. Basically if the new tab opened and was a one-and-done then it makes it easy to get back to where you were.

Here are some use cases of when this works and when it doesn't in Safari:

- Browse a page with links > click a link that opens in a new tab > Back action > **new tab closes**
- Browse a page with links > click a link that opens in a new tab > Click another link in that new tab to go to a new page > Back action > goes back one page > Back action > **no effect** (because you've acted in this new tab, so it drops this different behavior)
- Browse a page with links > middle click to open a link in a new tab > Back action > **no effect** (because it wasn't opened via a `target="_blank"` or similar by the host page, but by a user interaction
- Open a new tab manually > Navigate > Back action > **no effect** (won't close a user tab if user opened it on purpose

You can see that it's a pretty narrow range of when this behavior works, but I'd love to find a way to replicate the behavior here. Anybody seen a solution for something like this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this extension does the trick for Firefox:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/back-to-close-we/

For reference, this is the Chromium equivalent: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-on-back/pejmaahmbkcgbilcnckdadngeibiekbd

Comment: Yesss! Thank you!